# onMessageReceived Method Not Called when app in Background in FCM PushNotification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am stuck with this issue: when my application is in background and I click on a notification, it is supposed to start my desired activity(ChatActivity) but this is not happening.

I don't know how to use `getIntent.getExtra()` and I couldn't find the right solution to this issue.

I want to start the `ChatActivity` in question with some arguments when the notification is clicked instead the SplashScreen starts. The `ChatActivity` is supposed to start when my app is in foreground.

Here is my Code:

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    private static final String TAG = "FcmMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            System.out.println("Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            System.out.println("Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }
    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT| PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

AndroidManifest:-

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home.InboxActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home.HistoryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home.DetailMail"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Home.ChatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".PushNotification.FcmMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".PushNotification.FcmInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>
```

My Data Response

`data payload: {tag=, body=sdf, badge=90, image=xyz.png, sound=default, title=XYZ}`

Logs

```
10-19 18:01:49.455 25107-25174/? W/Babel: bcp TOOK TOO LONG! (15025ms > 10000ms)
10-19 18:01:49.561 25107-25187/? W/Babel: bcp TOOK TOO LONG! (15032ms > 10000ms)

                                          --------- beginning of system
10-19 18:01:49.663 750-1957/? W/Telecom: TelecomServiceImpl: null is not visible for the calling user
10-19 18:01:49.670 750-1623/? W/Telecom: TelecomServiceImpl: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.telephony.TeleConnectionService}, [e44cca915afc0390d8a77c0ff4608152603e7fa3], UserHandle{0} is not visible for the calling user
10-19 18:01:49.673 25107-25107/? I/Babel_telephony: TeleModule.updateConnectionManagerRegistration, registration preference changed from false to false
10-19 18:01:49.674 25107-25107/? W/Babel: BAM#gBA: invalid account id: -1
10-19 18:01:49.674 25107-25107/? W/Babel: BAM#gBA: invalid account id: -1
10-19 18:01:49.674 25107-25107/? I/Babel_telephony: TeleModule.updateIncomingCallRegistration, preferred account for incoming calls changed from: null to null
10-19 18:01:49.676 750-1965/? W/Telecom: TelecomServiceImpl: null is not visible for the calling user
10-19 18:01:49.678 750-1689/? W/Telecom: TelecomServiceImpl: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.telephony.TeleConnectionService}, [e44cca915afc0390d8a77c0ff4608152603e7fa3], UserHandle{0} is not visible for the calling user
10-19 18:01:49.851 25107-25199/? W/Babel: bcp TOOK TOO LONG! (15036ms > 10000ms)
10-19 18:01:49.957 1217-25451/? E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
10-19 18:01:49.996 313-25453/? D/ExtendedUtils: Try creating ExtendedExtractor
10-19 18:01:49.999 313-25453/? D/ExtendedUtils: Discarding default extractor and using the extended one
10-19 18:01:50.004 313-25453/? I/FFmpegExtractor: android-source:0xaab8c268
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'android-source:0xaab8c268':
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:   Metadata:
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     major_brand     : M4A 
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     minor_version   : 0
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     creation_time   : 2009-08-12 22:37:16
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     title           : Facebook Pop
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     artist          : Facebook
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     compilation     : 0
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     gapless_playback: 0
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     encoder         : iTunes 8.2.1, QuickTime 7.6.2
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     iTunSMPB        :  00000000 00000840 000000E1 00000000000016DF 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     Encoding Params : vers
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     iTunNORM        :  000001AE 00000000 000001AE 00000000 00000000 00000000 00007F16 00000000 00000000 00000000
10-19 18:01:50.013 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:   Duration: 00:00:00.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 191 kb/s
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 24 kb/s (default)
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:     Metadata:
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? I/FFMPEG:       creation_time   : 2009-08-12 22:37:16
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? D/FFmpegExtractor: FFmpegExtrator, url: android-source:0xaab8c268, format_name: mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, format_long_name: QuickTime / MOV
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? I/FFmpegExtractor: adjust mime(video/mp4 -> audio/mp4a-latm)
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? D/FFmpegExtractor: suppoted codec(aac) by official Stagefright
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? D/FFmpegExtractor: ffmpeg detected media content as 'audio/mp4a-latm' with confidence 0.08
10-19 18:01:50.014 313-25453/? D/ExtendedUtils: Try creating ExtendedExtractor
10-19 18:01:50.023 313-25453/? D/ExtendedUtils: Discarding default extractor and using the extended one
10-19 18:01:50.024 1217-25451/? E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
10-19 18:01:50.027 750-1623/? I/MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@22fd031a req=3flags=0x0
10-19 18:01:50.029 313-16421/? D/NuPlayerDriver: start(0xaab5fe68)
10-19 18:01:50.029 313-25452/? I/GenericSource: start
```

Please can you help me with the solution to this problem?

Comment: send your app background and send new notification  and provide this log

Comment: @GaneshPokale :- I am not getting your required?

Comment: your onMessageReceived Method Not Called when app in Background right?

Comment: then send app in Background and then send one notification from server... and that time you get some logs... update that log here

Comment: @GaneshPokale i have updated..

Comment: sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
 add this line at the end of onMessageReceived and filter only this app log

Comment: @GaneshPokale done but not prgress.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.. when you got json response by FCM in Data Payload, `system.out.println(getIntent.getExtra())` you get the Value from system tray and we can manage our activity through this.

here code of Launcher ACtivity

```
 bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                if(bundle!=null) {
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            Object value = bundle.get(key);
            Log.d("DATA_SENT", String.format("%s %s (%s)", key, value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
            System.out.println("messa vale" + String.format("%s %s (%s)", key, value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));

            if (key.equals("changeit_id")) {
                valu = value.toString();
                System.out.println("messa Value found:" + value);
            }
        }
    }
        if(!valu.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("item_id", valu);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here is the trick. Save the message in my Case I used sharedpref u can use Const to hold the message or pass it through Etra on intent. Happy coding :>)

```
public class SplashScreen extends Acivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    //When Notification is tapped
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        //init message
        String message = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("message"));
        String title = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().get("title"));
        //save the message
        MySharedPreference.save(getApplicationContext() , "message" , message);
        MySharedPreference.save(getApplicationContext() , "title" , title);

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext() , ChatActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

on The Firebase Console this is where the key message and title i have specified

[Firebase.Console see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpdme.png)

```
public final class MySharedPreference {

public static void save(Context context ,String key , String value){
    SharedPreferences prefs= context.getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key,value);
    editor.apply();

}

public static String getValue(Context context ,String key){
    //if 1st time , register the user
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString(key , "");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per [Firebase handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) there are two types of messages: data and notification. If you app is in background and you send a notification message, `onMessageReceived` will not be called. These are the two exceptions when `onMessageReceived` is not called:

> **Notifications delivered when your app is in the background.** In this
>   case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A
>   user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>   foreground.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>   device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
>   of the intent of your launcher Activity.

If `remoteMessage.getData()` and `remoteMessage. getNotification()` both are not null and app is in background state then data part is received in extras of your launcher activity. From there you will have to explicitly call your chat activity.

[image]

Comment: i have know all that but what is the problem of my code? can you post some code error in my code? i get the data from data payload.

Comment: What is your entire json message? Does it include any notification part? I mean is remoteMessage.getNotification() null or not?

Comment: remoteMessage.getNotification() is not null , i get same response like data. but my onmessagerecive method is not call when i got notification and click it. (app in Backgound) , instead of foreground i capable to go ChatActivity.

Comment: If `remoteMessage.getData()` and `remoteMessage. getNotification()` both are not null and if app is in background state then notification will not be received in `onMessageReceived`. Check `getIntent.getExtra()` inside `onCreate` of your launcher activity which gets the data payload.

Comment: Random:- it means onmessagerecive never call when app in background ?

Comment: `onmessagerecieived` is called in background state only if `remoteMessage.getNotification()` is null. For messages with both notification and data payload and app in background state, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126103/discussion-between-random-and-mayank-sugandhi).

Answer (score 0):

add click_action in admin.php

```
$fields = array(

        'to'                        => $reg_id ,
        'priority'                  => "high",
        'notification'              => array( "title" => "Android Learning", "body" => $message, "tag" => $tag, "click_action" => "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" ),
        'data'                      => array("message" =>$message, "image"=> $img_url),
    );
```

and set click_action to OPEN_ACTIVITY_1 to trigger an intent filter like the following:

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```